# tomcat behind apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, proxy

i am trying to use the mod_proxy_ajp to forward all the request from **tocat.example.com** to **example.com:8080**
here is what the tomcat **server.xml** looks like:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

and here is the **apache.conf** config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName tomcat.example.com
        ServerAdmin amdin@gmail.com
        ErrorLog logs/tomcat.example.com-error_log
        CustomLog logs/tomcat.example.com-access_log common
        <Proxy *>
                AddDefaultCharset Off
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / ajp://example:8009/
        ProxyPassReverse / ajp://example:8009/
</VirtualHost>
```

but it is not working, any idea?

Comment: Aren’t you just missing `.com` from your urls in your `ProxyPass` lines?

Comment: Is there any information in your logs?

Answer (score 0):

[first half of answer removed; misread question]

http://www.vakuumverpackt.de/tcptunnel/

(in shell)

```
$ tcptunnel --local-port=PORT --remote-host=IP-TO-TOMCAT --remote-port=8009
```

Comment: i don't want to redirect all connection from a port to another , i want to redirect specific hostname to another port, kind like of an load balancer maybe？is squid good for this?

Comment: Only one service can run on one port, so if port 8009 is in use by the ajp:// protocol, then TCPTunnel should still work. You run that on the Apache server. Any other port in use on the Tomcat server would not be proxied.